# Add data to column based on values from other columns

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataset, which looks like this

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A       B    NA
AA      C    NA
D       CC   NA
E       F    NA
```

I would like to add data to col3 based on condition. If col1 and col2 only have one letter each, write "SNP". If col1 has more than one letter, write "DEL" and if col2 has more than one letter, write "INS"

Final product would be:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A       B    SNP
AA      C    DEL
D       CC   INS
E       F    SNP
```

Anyone would know how to do this in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(magrittr); library(dplyr); library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(Col3 = case_when(str_length(Col1) == 1 & str_length(Col2) == 1 ~ "SNP",
                                 str_length(Col1) > 1 ~ "DEL",
                                 str_length(Col2) > 1 ~ "INS")
                )

  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    A    B  SNP
2   AA    C  DEL
3    D   CC  INS
4    E    F  SNP
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two nested `ifelse` statements.
So, for example, using `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(nchar(Col1)>1,"DEL",ifelse(nchar(Col2)>1,"INS","SNP")))

  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    A    B  SNP
2   AA    C  DEL
3    D   CC  INS
4    E    F  SNP
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I received an error message with " Evaluation error: argument "no" is missing, with no default". Not sure how to solve that yet.

Comment: This error is given when no `no` argument is given to `ìfelse` which needs three arguments (test, yes, no). See `?ifelse`. But it shouldn't be the case here, are you sure you wrote exactly the same syntax?